# No entiendo el siguiente método

Tags: java, poo, herencia

```
    public boolean isMember(int id) {
        for (Contact c : this.members) {
            if (c instanceof Group) {
                if (c.getId() != id) {
                    if (((Group) c).isMember(id)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (id == c.getId()) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

- Un método llamado isMember(...) al que se le pasa por parámetro un identificador de contacto y devuelve verdadero si está contenido en el grupo (directa, o indirectamente), y falso, si no se encuentra.

Estoy realizando un ejercicio de mensajería electrónica con diferentes clases y aplicando herencia. Al realizar este método me surge una serie de dudas. Entiendo que el for recorre una lista llamada members que tiene elementos de tipo contact, en el siguiente paso no tengo muy claro cual es la función del instanceof, ya que cuando no se cumple la función va a otra condición que no entiendo.

También me surge una duda con:

```
if (((Group) c).isMember(id))
```

Ya que no entiendo esta sintaxis para la condición.

Me gustaría que alguien me explicase en si un poco como funciona dicho método.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo que el operador **instanceof** devuelve true si el objeto **c** es una instancia(objeto) de la clase **Group**, en caso contrario devolverá false. Y para tu segunda duda **if (((Group) c).isMember(id))** se esta realizando un casting, convirtiéndo el objeto a la clase Group.

[Casting de objetos](https://www.solvetic.com/tutoriales/article/1041-casting-de-objetos-en-java/)